# #SwiftUI How to create an "Add task" button like iOS Reminders app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to create in my app a button like the "add task" button in the reminders app.

[image: First Screenshot]

This is pretty simple, I wrote a code like this below:

```
      NavigationView {
        ZStack(alignment: .leadingBottom) {
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    List {
                       //list items here
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .navigationBarTitle("Reminders")
                
            }
            
            Button(action: {}) {
              HStack {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                  .resizable()
                  .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                Text("New Task")
              }
            }.padding(.leading)
        }
    }
```

but **how to create the same effect of the reminders app when the task are more and exceed the available screen space?**

[image: Second screenshot]

As you can see, now the "add task button" has a background.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Just guessing - have you tried adding a background with blur effect to the button? When there is nothing under it, the blur should have no effect and it will appear as of there was no background 

Comment: @Losiowaty I'll try, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a view things in your code that i find very confusing. It does not make much sense to put a list into a scrollView, because a list is always scrollable.
I also changed the Zstack with a Vstack and there is no background issue anymore.
Here is the code:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        
        List(0..<100, id: \.self) {
            Text($0.description)//list items here
        }
            
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .navigationBarTitle("Reminders")
        
        
        
        Button(action: {}) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                Text("New Task")
            }
        }.padding(.leading)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my error, in my real code there isn't a List but a ForEach instead, so this is why I embedded it in a ScrollView